# Bounty after Serial voting..?

Tags: support, bounties, serial-voting

Say someone gets a Mortarboard due to serial up-voting. I know that badges can't be reversed. But, *votes* can. This case is somewhat interesting and I'm curious. Today (over Physics.SE), [this user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23503/nonagon) got a load of up-votes. In fact, [we were discussing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/nonagon) about the upvoter & the reversing scheme (see the whole transcript). Within a few minutes, the guy cleverly used this 200 rep. to offer a bounty [over this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64658/11062)

What I'm wondering is: The engine has recorded the pattern of votes. It will definitely do the reversing. Now, this guy only has 25 rep. The minimum rep. score that a SE user can have is **1**. So, the score can't go negative (neither zero).

So to be clear, what would happen tomorrow? Can the system be cheated this way?

---

*To future viewers:* The problem has been resolved and the bounty has been revoked. See his profile.  I think the rule has been implemented that Bounty shouldn't be awarded if one experiences serial upvoting

Comment: Barring moderator intervention, the votes would get reversed and the user will get a "rep change" entry in his history.

Comment: @Mysticial: So, you agree with me. OP loses only 25 rep..! Let's see tomorrow ;-)

Comment: Add this in transcript: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/nonagon

Comment: Correct, the OP's rep used for the bounty is essentially free.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vaD8Y.png) little thing caught my eye. :D

Comment: @hjpotter92: Yep... Well, we can't understand that *big-number*. Actually, I can't digest that -1049..! Any questions explaining that? :D

Comment: This situation has been brought to the attention of the team. Human intervention will be necessary to prevent the system being gamed in this way.

Comment: so he has two accounts or his friend upvoted him...

Comment: Pffft physicists... always looking to bend the rules of the system.

Comment: @slugster: Hah..! Declared as *"physicist"* before completing my undergrad course :P

Answer (score 4):

When a deletion or a reversal event causes a bounty to make a user's rep go negative, a "rep change" event is added to the user's history to "give" the user enough rep to place the bounty.

So barring moderator intervention, the upvotes will be reversed and a "rep change" event will be registered to give the user enough rep to leave him with 1 rep after the bounty.

In such a case, yes the rep used for the bounty is essentially free.

Comment: I don't *quite* agree with your last line. Poor guy doesn't know whether some *cruel* scheme like serial-upvoting actually exist in SE..! Moreover, he's a new user... Mystical - Be merciful. BTW, I'll select this answer based on tomorrow's result ;-)

Comment: That's kinda what mod messages are for - to give the user a polite warning that some behavior isn't allowed.

Comment: Mod messages are totally Okay. But, *Isn't suspension cruel for a newbie..?* Anyways, it's totally upto the team. I'll check it out tomorrow..! ;-)

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ: No. also when newbie was himself once interested in it.http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9477267#9477267

Comment: @007: Like I've said already, if he really wants to, he should include it in the `about-me` ;-)

Comment: Us non-mods don't know if this is truely a new user. If it not the first time, then a suspension is possible. That said I'm not a mod so I don't know what the policies are.

Comment: @Mysticial: BTW, *non-mods* can check out the user profile. It shows `33 days`. Isn't that a good evidence for new user?

Comment: I hate to sound negative but non-mods can't tell if a user has other accounts. I'm not trying to imply that's the case here, but I'm just suggesting another possibility.

Comment: @Mysticial: Ahh... I see your point. BTW, You *being a non-mod* had actually guessed the truth ;-)

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ I've seen enough of these cases where I can instantly identify them with a low chance of false-positive. But nevertheless, I usually hesitate to jump to conclusions since I can't see anywhere near as much information as mods can. :)