# Bounty wrongly assigned to my answer

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

It seems OP accepted the valid answer which solved his problem after bounty has been assigned to my answer.

Here is the post:

[consuming xml webservice using retrofit Parameter `soap12:Body` does not have a match in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442361/consuming-xml-webservice-using-retrofit-parameter-soap12body-does-not-have-a/55513390#55513390)

Now I want to assign bounty back to the answer which OP accepted as I believe in ethical/honest society.

Please help me with that how to assign it to valid answer? as I'm not finding any option rather than starting bounty myself on the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking into the question, it looks like the author accepted an answer 25 minutes after the bounty's grace period ended.

As such, as your answer was the highest-scored answer posted within the bounty period (with a score of at least 2), your answer was automatically awarded half the bounty. (If the author had accepted their answer before the grace period ended, they would have been automatically awarded the full bounty.)

Keep in mind that the bounty owner is notified multiple times about the ending of their bounty, and the expectation is on them that they will adequately award it on time if they want it to go to a specific answer. The provision that half the bounty is awarded to a top-voted answer mostly exists in case the bounty owner intentionally decides not to give the full amount to an existing answer; it helps reward those who made an attempt to answer the question for their effort. So there's nothing "dishonest" in keeping the bounty for yourself; you were awarded half the bounty for your effort, the bounty owner didn't award the bounty despite being notified multiple times of its ending, and the community thought your answer was relevant.

If you really want to hand the bounty over to the other answer, the best thing you can do is to start your own bounty on the question and award it to their answer. Note that unless you're willing to give away some of your own rep, they will also only pocket half the bounty. If the author is *really* intent on giving them the full bounty, they can try and get a moderator to clear away their previous bounty, so that they can start a new one and give it to the accepted author. Keep in mind that if a moderator chooses to do this, they are doing so out of niceness, and are under no obligation to do such a thing. It's probably easier to just award them the half of the bounty you earned yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I have already notified the author regarding the same. I will wait for some time for his reply and in either case I will assign it myself.

Comment: Moderators can cancel awarded bounties??? Makes sense as a measurement against reputation fraud, but still. Are you sure?

Comment: @MEE no they can't. Think OP means he will start a new bounty and award it manually to the answer that should have gotten it in the first place.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Actually, they can. This was done in [this case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181807/bounty-after-serial-voting) where a 1-rep user had put up a 200-rep bounty shortly after being serially upvoted and hitting the rep cap. Additionally, it's [possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301852/why-was-this-bounty-vote-deleted) for SE employees to manually reverse an awarded bounty from an answer.